# Perform something onTouch if parent ScrollView doesn't handle it

Tags: android, scrollview, touch-event, motionevent

OK, this might be trivial, but I can't figure out how to do it.

We have a container scrolling view, a subclass of `ScrollView`, and this view has a child view (among others) which should listen to touch events.

In particular, what I'd like to do is:

- `childView` is clicked and `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` comes;
- check if that event is a scrolling event, i.e., check if that action would start a scroll on the `scrollView`;
- if so, let the `scrollView` handle it and do nothing; if not, i.e. if the click upon `childView` did not start a scroll onto the parent view, *do something*.

Any ideas?

Pseudocoding, it should be something like:

```
ScrollView scrollView = ...;
View childView = scrollView.findViewById(...):

childView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            if (scrollView.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                // event was handled by the view
                return false;
            } else {
                // do something
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

As you can see I have not much insight on how motion events work.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly and if this helps you what you're trying to achieve, but how about intercepting the event in your parent ViewGroup (i.e., the ScrollView)? I mean via [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)